# How can I use a variable as Field Name in SQl?

Tags: sql, delphi, variables

```
procedure TfrmMainMenu.btnSearchClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  sFieldName,sSearchInfo:string;
begin
  sFieldName:=  cmbFieldNames.Text;

 if sFieldName='Field Names' then
 begin
   ShowMessage('Please Select A Vaild Field!!:(');
 end
 else
 begin
   sSearchInfo:=InputBox('Search for'+' '+ sFieldName,'Enter the '+' '+sFieldName,'') ;

    RunSql('SELECT *  FROM PackageTB  WHERE"'+sFieldName+'"="'+sSearchInfo+'" ') ;//Procedure to run Sql

 end; //Gets Data to Search from
```

Comment: Don't put quotes around the column name

Comment: This code suffers from SQL Injection attacks waiting to happen. You need to sanitize the user's input before you put it into the SQL. For instance, make sure `sFieldName` and `sSearchInfo` do not contain any unescaped `"` or `;` chars. `sSearchInfo` can be sanitized by using `AnsiQuotedStr()` instead, or better a parameterized query. You can't specify column names via query parameters, though, so you will still have to sanitize `sFieldName` manually either way, or simply do not allow the user to enter field names directly, use a ListBox or ComboBox instead to choose from.